# Left Button in UISplitViewController's Detail View Unable to Show UITabBarController (i.e. Master View)

Tags: xcode, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am unable to show the master view (i.e. UITabBarController) by pressing the left button in the detail view. Codes below are how I implemented the UISplitViewControllerDelegate to set up the left button.

I am using iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5.

```
#pragma mark - UISplitViewControllerDelegate
#warning "incomplete implementation"

- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
   shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
              inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) ? YES : NO;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc {
    barButtonItem.title = aViewController.title;

    NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [toolbarItems insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
    self.toolbar.items = [toolbarItems copy];
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
  invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
    NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [toolbarItems removeObject:barButtonItem];
    self.toolbar.items = [toolbarItems copy];
}
```

Comment: One more observation is that I am able to slide out the master view by using a swipe gesture. It is just the left button that is not working.

Comment: Problem solved. I replaced the UIToolbar with a UINavigationController and I am able to show the master view by clicking on the left button now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I replaced the UIToolbar with a UINavigationController and I am able to show the master view by clicking on the left button now.

Comment: I have same issue. What method should I call? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334939/uisplitviewcontroller-how-to-present-master-view-in-the-detail-view-by-button

Comment: Is your scenario the same as mine? If yes, I did not edit any codes to make it work. The only change is the replacement of the UIToolbar with a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, by setting the split view controller delegate and implementing this two methods you should be ready to go.

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
    {
        //remove button from navigation bar in detail navigation controller
        ((UINavigationController*)[svc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }

- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc{

        //add button to navigation bar in detail navigation controller
        barButtonItem.title = @"Navigation";
        ((UINavigationController*)[svc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;

    }
```

The instance of barButtonItem handles all the toggle process for you.