# UISplitViewController : how to present master view in the detail view by button event instead of via a swipe gesture

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

Swipe gesture is cool to present master view in portrait orientation. But I want to know how to present the table by button event instead of via a swipe gesture. I do not want to present popover, I like the slide animation.  Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved. This site is helpful. https://www.erianna.com/persistant-popover-in-uisplitviewcontroller

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, by setting the split view controller delegate and implementing this two methods you should be ready to go.

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
    {
        //remove button from navigation bar in detail navigation controller
        ((UINavigationController*)[svc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }

- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc{

        //add button to navigation bar in detail navigation controller
        barButtonItem.title = @"Navigation";
        ((UINavigationController*)[svc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;

    }
```

The instance of barButtonItem handles all the toggle process for you.